# Error installing TeamViewer on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, dependencies, libraries, teamviewer

I was trying to install **TeamViewer v11.0.67687 (deb 32-Bit / 64-Bit Multiarch)** then I got all the i386 dependency error message.

Then installed all the packages manually

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But there is a package that didn't download called **libpng12-0**, when I try to install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/teamviewer_11.0.67687_i386.deb
```

it says

```
Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer:i386.
(Reading database ... 219696 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../teamviewer_11.0.67687_i386.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer:i386 (11.0.67687) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:i386:
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libpng12-0.

dpkg: error processing package teamviewer:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer:i386
```

So I tried downloading TeamViewer with **wget** but not working.

```
wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb
```

Also tried using **apt-get** instead of **dpkg** but neither is working

```
sudo apt-get install ./teamviewer_i386.deb
```

Even tried to install that f*** library with **gdebi** but still not working

```
sudo gdebi teamviewer_i386.deb

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libpng12-0
```

Help :'(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is too late. You need to fix up all dependencies before installing TeamViewer. The following command fixed my problem:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```